# ASP.NET Routing in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms

I'm trying to add a route in my web forms application by following this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#adding_routes_to_a_web_forms_application

I've added the route in my Global.asax file like so:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "/WebsiteName/{combinedPin}", "~/Default.aspx");
}
```

I then try to visit my website locally like this:

http:// localhost:12345/WebsiteName/test36u

But I get a resource cannot be found message so I don't think my route is correct. Can anybody see a problem with my code?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to specify the name of your website as part of the route, try with this code:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{combinedPin}", "~/Default.aspx");
```

With the above code, your link would look like:

```
http://localhost:12345/WebsiteName/test36u
```

If however your intention is that your users access your site using a segment named:  `WebsiteName` then use:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "WebsiteName/{combinedPin}", "~/Default.aspx");
```

But in the precedent code your users will have to access your resource as follows: (probably not the expected result though)

```
http://localhost:12345/WebsiteName/WebsiteName/test36u
```

Comment: Thanks Jupaol. Would I still be able to access Request.QueryString["combinedPin"] ? I want to be able to check to see if it exists for error handling...

Comment: Ignore me, I figured out I can get at it like this: Page.RouteData.Values["combinedPin"]