# How to change content based on the page name instead of querystring in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've a site, we are using ASP.NET 4.0, and right now our products content is managed like this

```
www.franko1.com/products.aspx?serie=2000
```

where the querystring **serie** is the product ID, so its value is taken and then the contents is extracted from the database.

Now for SEO reasons,  we've been asked to change the urls, so now they have to look like this:

```
What the boss want                    | Current Urls
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
www.franko1.com/Relief_Valves         | www.franko1.com/products.aspx?serie=2000
www.franko1.com/Inline_Flame_Arrester | www.franko1.com/products.aspx?serie=1000
www.franko1.com/Vent_Hatch            | www.franko1.com/products.aspx?serie=3000
```

and so on ...

Right now, we are using a masterpage and the products.aspx and as I said,  we take the querystring serie and we show the content based on its value, I have no idea how to do this using asp.net, I have read about **ISAPI_Rewrite** but I was wondering if there is a technique to approach this without dealing with the IIS server....

Well I don't know if I was clear, It is hard to explain,

Comment: I'm assuming that you can take "Relief_Valves" and get all of the info you need from the DB out of it, yes?  You just need to know how to map that to `www.franko1.com/somepage.aspx?someParam=Relief_Valves`?

Comment: I think it would be much easier to do `www.franko1.com/products/Relief_Valves`. Check out [url routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

Comment: [URL Re-writing rules can be written in web.config without any changes in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Comment: Routing using global.asax could be your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704745/asp-net-routing-in-global-asax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for that. You can achieve this via [routing](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx) (It's not just for MVC).

Routing has been available as a stand alone module for a while now, but with ASP.Net 4.0 you can now use routing for WebForms just as easily as you can with MVC.

You will need to add some routing to your Global.asax

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Products", "Products/{Name}", "~/Products.aspx");
    }

}
```

And with that you can now reference the route values in your page like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string prodName = Page.RouteData.Values["Name"].ToString();

    //Do lookup, etc...
}
```

Your URLs will end up looking like this:

> www.domain.com/products/Relief_Valves
>   www.domain.com/products/Widgets
>   www.domain.com/products/TrashCans

etc..

Nice and easy... and clean!

Answer (score 0):

URL rewriting was made just for exactly this purpose. The problem is that it really doesn't work with variable content directly appended to the root URL. There really isn't enough information for URL routing to separate such URLs from the rest of your URLs.

Would your boss accept www.franko1.com/p/Relief_Valves ?