# IIS URL Rewrite Module rule for aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

my question is simple and is probably asked,
i have a website `www.alovine.com`
and have a url `www.alovine.com/registration.aspx`.
now i want people to be able to open the page when they type `www.alovine.com/registration`
i.e. without the ".aspx" in the end.

i have searched for it and could not find the answer.
i have tried changing in webconfig using this:

```
<rule name="Rewrite ASPX">
    <match url="registration" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="registration.aspx" />
  </rule>
```

Comment: fond this here http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-rewrite-urls-from-aspnet-on-cloud-sites, i am not sure this is how to do it, i am using visual studio 2013 btw

Comment: I see that you're using IIS URL Rewrite Rules. Maybe ask about this at http://forums.iis.net/1152.aspx. Otherwise, this is a [sf] question, not a [so] question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this code on your Global.asax:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{registration}", "~/registration.aspx");
```

With the above code, your link would look like:

```
http://localhost:12345/alovine/registration
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but where to put in global.asax file??
In application.start ??

Comment: it says Error 3 The name 'routes' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\Ajiteesh\Desktop\Web\Vine\WebSite3\Global.asax 8 9 WebSite3

Comment: You need to instantiate RouteCollection to use the routes variable, here is a good topic for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704745/asp-net-routing-in-global-asax

Comment: Also, don't forget to include Web.Http and Web.Routing at your using statements

Comment: Hey felix appreciate your help but dint understand that method he said he solved it using Page.RouteData.Values["combinedPin"] but how do i use that in my context

Comment: Error 3 The type or namespace name 'RouteCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Ajiteesh\Desktop\Web\Vine\WebSite3\Global.asax 4 39 WebSite3

Comment: i did this public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("", "{registration}", "~/registration.aspx");
    }

Comment: where to put Web.Http and Web.Routing

Comment: On your usings (top page), also you need to reference it on your project

Comment: Felix i have not created a project file i just started creating the website by saying new website and then adding new item in website menu, this is my first asp.net website, and i am guessing you want me to do this in project file right?? or the registration.aspx.cs file

Comment: Try it, create a mvc project to figure out how routes works.
good luck

Comment: and wht should come in action/categoryname

Comment: Error 3 The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Ajiteesh\Desktop\Web\Vine\WebSite3\Global.asax 3

Comment: Yes, change on global!
Man, you need to refence it, click with your right mouse button on your project then add references, and add it! >> System.Web

Comment: I think it worked felix !!

can you navigate to www.alovine.com/registration

thanks a lot buddy